# Changing setConetentView with setOnClickListener causes program to crash (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-layout, button, nullpointerexception

So my program worked fine until I wanted to added my "mainmenu". I want to press a button on my mainmenu and then make it go to "start_board", so this is what I basicly made that is new. If I don't give enough information please inform me, i'm very new to programming.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);  

    Button splayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.splay);

    splayButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    splayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.start_board);

        //code, code and more code

        }
    }); 
}
```

mainmenu XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainmenu" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splay"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat

```
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244): Process: com.gerfort.gerfortrps, PID: 22244
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:185)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
11-12 11:41:21.272: E/AndroidRuntime(22244):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use another Activity, not change the content of the current on. Take a look at some tutorial.

Comment: setContentView call in one time not more time use layout id and change colour of layout

Comment: Naveen, the thing is I need everything that is on the "start_board" like buttons etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Fragments`. And use a transaction to change the current UI when the user press on the button

Comment: Yes, that will probably do. Thanks.